# Table View Inside a ViewController is not showing fully (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, viewcontroller

[image]

I can't get this to work. I have 3 other view controllers that have a working table view inside them, and I have done everything the same way. Hopefully someone have a simple solution for me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the code that you are using? Or are you using storyboards? Any sort of additional information would be helpful here!

Comment: Are you using Auto Layout? Have you tried using the view debugger?

Comment: In all likelihood, your frame is wrong or your auto-layout constraints are wrong.

Comment: How do i use the view debugger? I would guess it's something related to constraints since my other tableViews did not have any and the size inspector suggest that there was constraints before! Also thanks for adding the picture Aaron!

Comment: The question is resolved, i had accidentally added a constraint before, and that apperently removes the auto constraint feature that xcode have when you never added any constraints (xCode say this about my other Tableviews: "The selected views have no constraints. At build time, explicit left, top, width, and height constraints will be generated for the view.")

Thanks to everyone that helped out!

Comment: You should consider adding full constraints instead of leaving it with no constraints. Remove any ambiguity.